# Unable to retrieve TempData value

Tags: dd4t

I am using DD4T for tridion with mvc.net application. I am not able to fetch Tempdata value in the controllers action after redirecting it.
The code is as below
This is the login code where on successful login I am saving username in Tempdata which I want to use in redirect page.

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    string userName = Request.Form["username"];
    string password = Request.Form["password"];
    if (!ValidateUser(username,password)
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["username"]= username;
        return Redirect("/index.html");
    }
}
```

The Page controller (using default implementation of DD4t for .net) is as below

```
public class PageController : TridionControllerBase
{
    [HandleError]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public override System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Page(string pageId)
    {               
        if (TempData.ContainsKey("username"))
        {
            //this never get executed
            Log("contains temp data");
        }

        return base.Page(GetRelativePath(pageId));
    }
}


routes.MapRoute(
    "TridionPage",
    "{*PageId}",
    new { controller = "Page", action = "Page" }, // Parameter defaults
    new { pageId = @"^(.*)?$" } // Parameter constraints
);
```

In this pagecontroller i am not getting any value in Tempdata. I am new to DD4T and want to confirm if there is any additional hook that DD4T places in the request pipleline which is wiping out the value stored in tempdata. I am able to run the code if I don't use DD4t and hence I have not posted the question in any .net forum.

Comment: It seems to me that the first step would be to use the same key for the data in both places :) In the login, you are using "username", but in the redirect page you are checking for "Authenticated".

Comment: apologies, i was changing the key name and that was by mistake, In actual code the keys are same.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't omitted anything important here (it looks like you have definitely stripped some stuff out since you have mismatched brackets in your posted code)? Between your `TempData["username"]` assignment and `ContainsKey` call DD4T has no involvement - the normal MVC pipeline is used.

Comment: yes, I removed some of the code lines as it was not relevant to my question, There were no compile time error. I just want to know if there is any difference in request processing between a normal mvc.net application and a dd4t application. I can see it uses a wildcard route for all the pages. And only one action page in page controller provides all the pages. In page action the TempData is checked before calling base.Page(GetRelativePath(pageId)) and it should persist value for single redirect which it is not.

Comment: I tested it with DD4T (.NET 4.5.1) on IIS 8.5 (Win 2012 R2) and it just worked. Can you verify if you have Session State enabled? There are differences between Cassini and IIS. Double check if there's no request happening just before the redirect (async JavaScript call)

Comment: Yes, I already checked session state and it was enabled. Beside this I also checked it fhere is any js call in between the requests. But we are using reverse proxy using ARR which might be causing this issue by intercepting the request.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. These days TempData should persist until the request in which it's actually accessed again (i.e. beyond the scope of the subsequent request as it did originally). At any rate, this is a .NET/MVC problem, not a DD4T one as DD4T is certainly not what's preventing the TempData entry from persisting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem cannot be reproduced from the information provided and is not directly related to Tridion or the DD4T framework.